# I cannot view my JSON object in the console nor the terminal but I get a 200 status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post, get

I am trying to get data points out of an API. I've used the authentication credentials and token to access and I get a status message 'ok' with a 200 code. I know I'm accessing but I cannot view the points nor stream any data in the terminal nor the console in the DOM.

1) I test this with Postman and I can get all the data in the terminal

```
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.url.io/rest/method/url-api/getDeviceData',
    qs: { happy_token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ImlkfDM4ZDQ4OWM1LWI3YzUtNDE1Ni05ZWJlLWJmYzViMmJkODk1OXx0eXBlfHRpbWVzdGFtcHxpc0VuY3J5cHRlZHxvcmlnaW58MTAtMC0yOC0xODFfNTcwMDB8cG9saWN5fDHRsfGluYWN0aXZpdHlfdGhyZXNob2xkfDF8aXNUb2tlbnx1c2VybmFtZXxtb2hhbWVkLmZheWVkQHBkaWNvcnAuY29tfEd8NHwtMnw1fDZ8N3wkOHwkOXxIfEF8LTNdfEJ8JDl8SXxBfC0zXV18Q3wtMXxEfEVdIg.PaQdlILLK9lWN8zjmthTgWY_r77oBw' },
    headers:
    {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        cookie: 'AWSALB=A+sdBzwAGrQmRer2y4ENHQgCc8TdDKiLHkM68CJMVKNhpVEBkiW53AhWSRKmzwk9scGKbSHeWtWL9YzuBayGFyWdkmkd5fkFSp2FYxbraW75UOoi8YtY',
        Host: 'www.url.io',
        'Postman-Token': '08e1668d-1f49-4451-a47e-61c9bae9df08,84944b9f-17eb-4520-88b2-344a7c46bdca',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Accept: '*/*', 
        'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.13.0',
        Authorization: 'Basic bW9oYW1lZC5ZEBwZGljb3JwLmNpAbWZheWVkMjk5OA=='
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
```

After I run `npm start` I get a beautifully JSON response:

```
      "message": "Call successful",
      "data": {
        "device_id": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "parameters": {
                        "node_id": "1",
                        "ip_address": "172.00.00.00",
                        "tcp_id": "1"
                    },
                    "type": "P",
                    "mapping": "P",
                    "name": "P name",
                    "deviceName": "P name",
                    "path": "/profileView/devices/p name",
                    "deviceType": "P",
.
.
.
(etc)
```

This is what I want to get to!

However, when writing my code, as follows:

```
    var credentials = function getCredentials() {
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        xhr.open("GET", URL, true, username, password);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = receiveResponse;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send();
        xhr.open("POST", URL)

        function receiveResponse(e) {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    var response = this.responseXML
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getToken(credentials) {
        var data = response;
        for (var i = 0; response[i]>1; I++) {
            var results = response[i];
            console.log(response[i]);
        }
    }


    // server instance
    const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
        response.end("hello azure");
        console.log(response);
    });


    const port = process.env.PORT || 443;
    server.listen(port);

    console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

this is what I get in the terminal:

[terminal response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y9Vi.png)

Additionally, I can't see anything in the console log here:
[Browser View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMGZN.png)
I feel like I am sending the right request but I cannot POST the data. Can anyone provide any insight? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @lurker for your response. I tried doing that and I get "undefined"

Comment: Sorry got this confused with a different language lib. :-/ How about `console.log(this.responseText)` (inside your `receiveResponse` function). See, [XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but can you clarify why you're doing a `GET` followed by a `POST`? Just trying to reconcile the Postman example with your code.

Comment: @lurker I tried that, it makes no difference. I did notice that when I iterate through my data I was supposed to use data, rather than response since I stored my response in the data variable. Even 'fixing' that still gives me the same response.

Comment: @hacksalot that's a good question. I am not sure how Postman is passing out its token and getting the response. I am using GET and POST because I'm first trying to get access to the URL, then POST the response with its data. I may have done this more complex than it could have been, so I am open to suggestions